# Updating a JPanel of queried results from a database

Tags: java, user-interface

When a user clicks a button initially, a query is run and each row is put into a JPanel and added to the display for the user to view. Which works fine.

My problem is, I want the user to be able to filter these results according to values that they provide ( through a JTextField ) , and I want the displayed records to update as the value of the JTextField changes. My queries are formed and executed each time the JTextField is changed, but I can't find a way to update the records displayed.

Any help would be appreciated.

The code took a while to edit to the satisfaction of stackoverflow, but here it is. Hopefully you can follow the logic. This is the method that deals with formation and execution of the queries, which works(again).
The problem is displaying the new results.

```
private void processSearch(){

int count = 0;
double width;

remove(allInfo);

allInfo = new JPanel();
allInfo.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 10));

Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
width = screenSize.getWidth();


try {

DatabaseConnetor connect = new      DatabaseConnetor();
Connection conn = connect.connect();
String query = "";
String whereClause = "";

int unEmpty = 0;

String [] searches ={searchNameTxt.getText(), searchMailTxt.getText(), searchContactTxt.getText(), (String) searchGender.getSelectedItem()};

String [][] keys = {{"first_name", "middle_name", "family_name", "surname"}, {"email"}, {"contact", "contact2"}, {"gender"}};

for(int i=0; i < searches.length; i++){                   
if(!searches[i].trim().isEmpty()){
unEmpty++;
}

for(int i=0; i < searches.length; i++){

int counter = 0;            

if(!searches[i].trim().isEmpty()){                  
whereClause += " AND ";             

int len = keys[i].length;                       

if(len == 1){
whereClause += " ("+keys[i][0]+" LIKE '%"+searches[i]+"%') ";
}else if(len > 1){

whereClause += " ( ";

while(counter < len){                           

if(counter == len-1)
whereClause += keys[i][counter]+" LIKE '%"+searches[i]+"%'";

else
whereClause += keys[i][counter]+" LIKE '%"+searches[i]+"%' OR ";

counter++;
}

whereClause += " ) ";
}
}
}

query = "SELECT photo, first_name, middle_name, family_name, surname, gender, email, contact, contact2 FROM user WHERE rights = 2" + whereClause;

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

String gen = "", middle = "", family = "", cont = "", phot = "";

ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while(result.next()){

JPanel data = new JPanel();

data.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(width*0.75), 50));

data.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 10));


if(result.getString(1) == "NULL")
phot = "";

data.add(new JLabel(phot)); //Photo

data.add(new JLabel(result.getString(2))); //First Name

if(result.getString(3) == "NULL")
middle = "";

data.add(new JLabel(middle)); //Middle Name

if(result.getString(4) == "NULL")
family = "";

data.add(new JLabel(family)); //Family Name

data.add(new JLabel(result.getString(5))); //Surname

if(result.getString(6).equals("M"))
gen = "Male";
else
gen = "Female";             

data.add(new JLabel(gen)); //Gender

data.add(new JLabel(result.getString(7))); //E-Mail

data.add(new JLabel(result.getString(8))); //Contact1

if(result.getString(9) == "NULL")
cont = "";

data.add(new JLabel(cont)); //Contact 2

allInfo.add(data);
}

add(allInfo);

connect.disconnect(conn);
connect = null;
conn = null;

} catch (SQLException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a query is run and each row is put into a JPanel and added to the display for the user to view

I would suggest you use a `JTable` to display the data from a database. A `JTable` is designed to display data in a row/column format.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and examples.

> I want the user to be able to filter these results according to values that they provide ( through a JTextField ) , and I want the displayed records to update as the value of the JTextField changes.

A `JTable` supports dynamic filtering of the data displayed in the table. The above tutorial has a section on `Sorting and Filtering` that shows how to filter as text is entered into a text field. Filtering the table is more efficient then redoing the SQL query.

Adding data to the table is straight forward. Instead of creating a panel with each column of data you can add a new row of data to the TableModel:

```
    String sql = "Select * from ???";
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();

    //  Get column names

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
    }

    //  Get row data

    while (rs.next())
    {
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
        }

        data.addElement( row );
    }

    //  Create table with database data

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
    {
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };

    JTable table = new JTable( model );
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
```